# How to show relationships in an optional manner in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have multiple nodes and relationships in neo4j, certain nodes have relationship depth as 4, while certain have 2. I'm using neo4j's HTTP API to get the data in graph format

Sample query:

```
MATCH p= (n:datasource{resource_key:'ABCD'})-[:is_dataset_of]-(c:dataset)-[q]-(v:dataset_columns)-[s]-(b:component)-[w]-(e:dashboard) return p
```

If i use this query then i can get output if this exact relationship is present but I also want to get the output if the 2nd relationship is not available, Any pointers on how to achieve this?

Comment: Are you really using different labels person1, person2 and person3 in your model ?

Comment: Oh no, this is an example. Now that you mention it, this is a poor example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
MATCH p = (:person1 {hobby: 'gamer'})-[:knows]-(:person2)
RETURN p
UNION ALL
MATCH p = (:person1 {hobby: 'gamer'})-[:knows]-(:person2)--(:person3)
RETURN p
```

The [UNION](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/union/#query-union) clause combines the results of 2 queries. And the `ALL` option tells `UNION` to not bother to remove duplicate results (since the 2 subqueries will never produce the same paths).

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the path to be returned, you can do something along these lines, using apoc (https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/3.4/nodes-relationships/path-functions/)

```
MATCH requiredPath=(n)-[r]->(m)
OPTIONAL MATCH optionalPath = (m)-[q]->(s)
RETURN apoc.path.combine(requiredPath,optionalPath) AS p
```

Comment: Any other way apart from using apocs?

Comment: it depends on what you want to do with the result. if it's just about visualising, you can do RETURN requiredPath,optionalPath

Comment: The reason for not moving forward with apocs is, the existing setup crashes when enabling apoc

Comment: IMHO, you should try to solve the issue that causes the crash first, because if not, you'll probably run with a sub-optimal set-up anyway, and that may haunt you in many different ways when going forward.